# Configure DNS Zone to Forward for any non-existant hosts

Tags: windows-server-2000, internal-dns, domain-name-system

Not sure if this is possible, but in my head, it sounds reasonable to be able to do. I'm just not sure how...

We have our company domain on our internal DNS servers (company.com), but the domain is hosted externally as well. We have the zone setup on a Win2k Server, and it is AD integrated.

What I want to be able to do, is for any hosts which do NOT exist on our internal DNS (queried by internal machines with that DNS server set manually), to then look at public DNS for the domain.

So:
On our internal DNS we have the company.com zone setup.
On public DNS we have the company.com zone setup, and add an A record for host name 'www'.
External machines lookup www.company.com, and resolve as normal, using public DNS.
Internal machines lookup www.company.com, cannot find it on internal DNS, forwards resolution to public DNS and finds the record.

Is this too much to ask? Or am I just going about it the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Windows DNS Server doesn't work that way. You have to add an A record with the IP of your website.

You can achieve something like this for subdomains of your primary, but it's a ugly trick and will not work in your situation.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that. So does that mean I'll have to manage the records on BOTH the internal and external DNS servers?

Comment: Yup - That's pretty much it. The only other thing which I wouldnt advise is to have your DNS server set as the name server for your domain ofc you would need ports etc...

Comment: Yep, unless you're willing to change your AD setup (significantly), you're stuck managing split DNS system. I'm sure the decisions were made 10+ years ago, but this is why name-space planning is very important when planning AD.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Not what I wanted to hear, but it's kinda what I expected...

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked about Wildcard Option? I think this would work perfect if you add Wildcard in your Local DNS forwarding zone which would resolve to external network.

If you have W2K8 in your environment and you can do conditional forwarding too.

Gaurav Maniar MCP | MCSE | MCST | MCITP | ITILv3 Certified